# Column Index not reflecting in Explain Plan for predicates with "IN" Statement

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with column name **IDENTIFIER** and the table (**TAB1**) has an index for this column. whenever i try to query a single data using a simple where clause with single value, explain plan shows that it is utilizing an existing index on that particular column.
But whenever i have a list of values in another table,  say a temporary table ( **TEMP_IDENTIFIER** ) with list of all identifiers that i want to query and when i frame a query on the same table with an **IN clause** , i could see that explain plan is not considering the index, instead it performs an full table scan on the table

Ideally i would want the second query to utilize the existing index as well

Please find the both the queries and explain plan as follows

---

**Query 1**

```
explain plan for
select * from schemaowner.TAB1 
where IDENTIFIER = 'A';
```

**Explain Plan**

```
Plan hash value: 4172144893

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                  |    51 | 12750 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TAB1             |    51 | 12750 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | COL_INDEX        |    51 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("IDENTIFIER"='A')
```

---

**Query 2**

```
explain plan for
select * from schemaowner.TAB1 
where IDENTIFIER in (select IDENTIFIER from SCHEMAOWNER.temp_IDENTIFIER);
```

**Explain Plan :**

```
Plan hash value: 935676029

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name             | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                  |  3135K|   822M|       | 74751   (1)| 00:14:58 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI|                  |  3135K|   822M|  2216K| 74751   (1)| 00:14:58 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | TEMP_IDENTIFIER  | 61115 |  1492K|       |    85   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | TAB1             |  3745K|   893M|       | 28028   (2)| 00:05:37 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("IDENTIFIER"="IDENTIFIER")

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

Comment: By the way, I think you mean the **execution plan** (the optimiser's approach to the query), not **explain plan** (the utility for predicting the likely execution plan).

Answer (score 0):

Thats the beauty of the optimizer. It's figured out (or costed) that a SEMI join is the most efficient method :)